# I cannot connect App to my PostgreSQL database - No Suitable Driver

Tags: java, android, database, postgresql

I'm doing a school project where I need to connect my app to a PostgreSQL Database.

I'm almost finishing, but I can't make the connection. I think I'm doing something wrong. I'll explain with some pictures.

This is the piece of code that it's probably causing the problem:

```
private Connection conn;
    private String host = "<--my ip here->>";
    private String db = "android";
    private int port = 5432;
    private String user = "android";
    private String pass = "android";
    private String url = "jdbc:postgresql://@s:@d:@s";


    public DB() {
        super();
        this.url = String.format(this.url, this.host, this.port, this.db);

        this.conecta();
        this.desconecta();
    }
```

I can't find PostgreSQL 10 on dependencies list when trying to add library dependencie, even though I've just installed it.

I also have this problem of 2 Databases showing on my PgAdmin 4, the 9.5 port is 5432 and the 10 is 5433, my database for the app is 9.5 (port 5432)

I've add theses ports exeptions to my firewall.

Could someone help me,please?

Comment: You should not try to connect to PostgreSQL directly from Android, you should connect to a web service or REST API and the backend powering that web service should connect to the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer on how excatly could I do that or what steps should I take?

Comment: Trying to answer that in a comment is hard, also is not appropriate to add it here as an answer since it is not your original quesstion. What I can say is, try to create a web service or REST API first, it would connect to PostgreSQL and your android app will connect to the web service or REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add newest postgres jdbc driver from central repository.

If it is android application it is better to create a web service and use it as proxy. In that case you can control load.

ps. piece of code got 5432 port and  "the 10 is 5433"

Comment: Here is my situation: https://i.imgur.com/j3kmS6u.png and https://i.imgur.com/G8LD0vU.png . I can't find any other to install when I click on add Library Dependecie

Comment: try to add this line to your config:

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

Comment: can you provide build.gradle file

Comment: Buidgradle from Module:app https://codeshare.io/2WWxJ8

Buildgradle from Project https://codeshare.io/5OJg8j

Comment: should be another there you write dependencies like:

compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.0-801.jdbc4'

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try